# php - Displaying special characters in a php file

Tags: php, database, character-encoding

I'm using various European characters (like ø, ą, ñ) in my database, but they are not correctly displayed in my php-file. I've tried some things (below) that I found in simmilar questions, but none of them works.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-ISO-8859-1">
  ...
</head>
```

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
</head>
```

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
echo "øąñ";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct displayed with `<meta charset="utf-8">`. If you are trying to get these characters from database, maybe you have not mysql [set_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) function used.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'database');
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```